# Which kinds of low level facilities aren't typically supported on multi-core machines?

Tags: optimization, multicore, cpu-architecture

I'm looking at some optimized, low level, cross platform, concurrency code designed to run on multi-core machines, and want to check some of its assumptions.

Support for hardware optimizations of some kinds aren't, probably, supported on multi core designs (for example, Out of Order Execution support [[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution)] seems like a good candidate - it takes a lot of surface area to implement, and can be a power hog). Does anyone have a list of other such facilities - ones typically available on single or small number of core machines, but typically left out from machines with larger number of cores on them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today, multicore machines are warmed-over die shrinks of uniprocessors.  You could almost imagine sawing a 4-core die into 4 1-core dice.  I exaggerate only a little bit.

In future, multicore machines will be more thoughtfully designed for energy efficiency and area efficiency.  You may see the same ISA, but with different mixes of resources (more or fewer numbers of duplicated functional units), and even with some sharing of resources between cores (e.g. AMD Bulldozer).  And, as you say, backing off from the complexity and energy overhead of no-holds-barred out-of-order execution.  This will most likely be perceived as different instruction-per-clock (IPC) differences (more or less performance) on the same instruction set architecture.

Also as vendors have to juggle a hypothetical portfolio of big out-of-order serial performance optimized cores and small in-order or less-out-of-order (OoO) and narrower, more energy efficient "throughput" cores, they will be challenged to keep these different implementations in sync with the evolutions of their ISAs.  Some cores may support new instructions, new state, new coprocessors, virtualization, security, etc. earlier than others.  This leads to a challenge of coding to the common denominator while also lighting up the new facilities for better perf or energy efficiency (or whatever) on those cores that have the new capabilities.

So to answer your specific question, all the traditional computer architecture techniques for trading gates for expressive-power, or performance, or energy efficiency may be rethought and selectively removed in future small throughput-oriented cores.

- Hardware multithreading
- Aggressive OoO -> humble OoO or even in-order execution
- High degrees of microarchitectural speculation
- Fancy branch predictors
- Big TLBs
- Fancy memory prefetchers
- Deep pipelines
- Wide issue / many copies of functional units
- Big caches, wide buses to caches
- ...

But it goes both ways.  It may also be that the new small throughput-optimized energy-optimized cores have new features not present in the older OoO cores.  For example, the Larrabee New Instructions (LRBni) (http://www.drdobbs.com/high-performance-computing/216402188) were proposed for a machine with dozens of simpler cores.  As another example, the small cores may turn to hardware multithreading to afford better memory latency tolerance to compensate for smaller private caches.

Also, having lots of small energy frugal cores means you may be willing to dedicate and therefore customize some of the cores to optimize performance for particular valuable workloads.  For example, the Tensilica custom processors and tools anticipate that some of your small cores will have additional instructions and custom problem-specific datapaths (accelerating an inner loop of video decoding, for example).  So in these cases the little core may (counter-intuitively) have much better performance than the much larger core.

Makes sense?

Happy hacking!

Comment: p.s. Since different implementations imply different microarchitectures, do not be surprised to see subtle microarch-induced differences between systems.  For example, you might never observe a subtle data race memory access interleaving on one microarch but it might occur often on another microarch. implementation of the same ISA.  (Ouch.)